# htaccess deny directory Internal Server Error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, directory

I typed this code below in .htaccess:

```
<Directory ./folder>
deny from all
</Directory>
```

But I get "Internal Server Error" in all website folders.

What's the problem in my code?

Answer (score 1):

You're getting 500 error because Apache `Directory` [directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory) is not allowed in .htaccess. You need to use in Apache config e.g. `httpd.conf` only.